# Create table with add_columns in PrettyTable

Tags: python, prettytable

I am trying to create a table of performance metrics using PrettyTable. Given the table layout, it would be best to fill the table by column using a list of metrics and a list of values with the `add_column` option. However, when I try to do that, the output gives all the lists values in a single row:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
mse=123
mae=456
r2=789
performance_metrics=['Mean Squared Error', 'Mean Absolute Error', 'R-Squared']
values=[mse, mae, r2]
#CREATE TABLE
table = PrettyTable()
table.title = 'Model Performance'
column_names=['Metric', 'Value']
table.add_column(column_names[0],[performance_metrics])
table.add_column(column_names[1],[values])
print(table)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              Model Performance                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                           Metric                           |      Value      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| ['Mean Squared Error', 'Mean Absolute Error', 'R-Squared'] | [123, 456, 789] |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

How can I fix this possibly without resorting to adding each row on its own?

UPDATE: Reading back the question I realized I forgot to attach the desired output, which is obviously something like the following:

```
        +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        |                              Model Performance                               |
        +------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
        |                           Metric                           |      Value      |
        +------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
        | Mean Squared Error                                         | 123             |
        +------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
        | Mean Absolute Error                                        | 456             |
        +------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+          
        | R-Squared                                                  | 789             |          
        +------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try use loop for that operation, at this moment u re adding whole list to one column:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
mse=123
mae=456
r2=789
performance_metrics=['Mean Squared Error', 'Mean Absolute Error', 'R-Squared']
values=[mse, mae, r2]
#CREATE TABLE
table = PrettyTable()
table.title = 'Model Performance'
column_names=['Metric', 'Value']
table.field_names = [column_names[0], column_names[1]]
```

u have to use add_row to abuse multipling same columns:

```
for i in range(len(performance_metrics)):
    table.add_row([performance_metrics[i],values[i]])
print(table)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------+
|      Model Performance      |
+---------------------+-------+
|        Metric       | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
|  Mean Squared Error |  123  |
| Mean Absolute Error |  456  |
|      R-Squared      |  789  |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: I see, I thought this would have been handled automatically using `add_column`. Thanks